# Is it good to use external HDD with a USB 3.0 7-Port Hub (TP-Link UH700) which is powered by a power adapter?

Tags: windows, usb, external-hard-drive, usb-3, usb-hub

I have a USB 3.0 7-Port Hub [(TP-Link UH700)](https://www.tp-link.com/us/home-networking/usb-hub/uh700/). It has a power adapter to power the USB Hub. And also I have 2 external Hard Disk Drives. My question is, I am plugging my 2 HDDs to USB Hub. So is it safe to use them with this kind of USB? Because even my computer is turned off HDDs are running because USB Hub is powered separately. So is it safe to use with that way and If I turn off the USB Hub Directly will it cause any errors/issues/failures to HDD like crashing? Or what is the safest way to use HDDs without any issues/ HDD failures happen with the time? Can anybody guide me? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HDD have a failure rate of under 1% overall. It is never best to remove any type of removable storage without first unmounting/ejecting it from the OS. I am unsure of how an independently powered hub would effect them(although it is unlikely to have a negative effect) but it is always best practice to unmount prior to removing or shutting the system down. Also, statistically, the more it is used the more likely it is to fail.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Yes I get it but so let's say I eject the HDD from OS but it still gets the power, So if I turned off the power to USB Hub will it still create issues to HDD?

Comment: Of course! It should not cause any issues because the logical connection between the OS and the HDD has been severed and it is only receiving power from the Hub not reading or writing information.

Comment: What about platters? There is something happening like HDD parking right? Will platters crashed with the header when suddenly powered off?

Comment: They will not. Most, if not all, modern HDD have a built-in mechanism that automatically parks the heads on power loss. When the head is parked it is out of the way of the platters. Usually drive corruption occurs when power loss happens while data is being transmitted(read/write).

Comment: Thank you very very much for the answer and the clarifications. Appreciate putting your time and effort to answer this question. 

Comment: @AbrahamArnold Absolutely my friend, take care!

Comment: Take care you too my friend.